# How to compute daily mean values for each column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe (df) with hourly reading of certain pollutants, from 2001 up to 2018. The df has the following info:

```
    date                    O_3     NO_2        SO_2        PM10        PM25        CO      
0   2001-01-01 01:00:00     7.86    67.120003   26.459999   32.349998   12.505127   0.45    
1   2001-01-01 02:00:00     7.21    70.620003   20.879999   40.709999   12.505127   0.48    
2   2001-01-01 03:00:00     7.11    72.629997   21.580000   50.209999   12.505127   0.41    
3   2001-01-01 04:00:00     7.14    75.029999   19.270000   54.880001   12.505127   0.51    
4   2001-01-01 05:00:00     8.46    66.589996   13.640000   42.340000   12.505127   0.19    
5   2018-04-30 20:00:00     63.00   58.000000   4.000000    2.000000    2.000000    0.30    
6   2018-04-30 21:00:00     49.00   65.000000   4.000000    5.000000    4.000000    0.30    
7   2018-04-30 22:00:00     49.00   58.000000   4.000000    5.000000    3.000000    0.30    
8   2018-04-30 23:00:00     48.00   52.000000   4.000000    7.000000    7.000000    0.30    
9   2018-05-01 00:00:00     52.00   43.000000   4.000000    6.000000    4.000000    0.30
```

I want to compute the mean value for each column based on day hours. In other words, for 2001-01-01 compute the mean value for hour 01 to 05. The above df is just a small example, the real df runs mostly for 24 hours a day, although they might be some days with less pollutant hourly readings. Once I have computed the mean value for each column I compute each row in order to get a Label.

The df has the following specs:

```
Index(['date', 'O_3', 'NO_2', 'SO_2', 'PM10', 'PM25', 'CO', 'Label'], dtype='object')
```

As far as NaN values:

```
date     0
O_3      0
NO_2     0
SO_2     0
PM10     0
PM25     0
CO       0
Label    0
dtype: int64
```

And as for general info:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 139608 entries, 0 to 139607
Data columns (total 8 columns):
#   Column  Non-Null Count   Dtype         
---  ------  --------------   -----         
0   date    139608 non-null  datetime64[ns]
1   O_3     139608 non-null  float64       
2   NO_2    139608 non-null  float64       
3   SO_2    139608 non-null  float64       
4   PM10    139608 non-null  float64       
5   PM25    139608 non-null  float64       
6   CO      139608 non-null  float64       
7   Label   139608 non-null  float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(7)
```

I've tried the following in order to group by date:

```
day_df = hour_df.groupby([hour_df.date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]).mean()
```

But I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it. If I check the df info I get:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 5824 entries, 2001-01-01 to 2018-05-01
Data columns (total 7 columns):
#   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
0   O_3     5824 non-null   float64
1   NO_2    5824 non-null   float64
2   SO_2    5824 non-null   float64
3   PM10    5824 non-null   float64
4   PM25    5824 non-null   float64
5   CO      5824 non-null   float64
6   Label   5824 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(7)
```

As it can be seen, not all days have 24 hours of pollutant readings, otherwise instead of only 5824 entries there would be 6329 entries. That's why I'm not sure if I am computing the mean values correctly.

I'd really like to know what would be the proper way to target what I'm looking for.

Comment: Where can you see 6329 entries? Your numbers are all consistent.

Comment: From 2001-01-01 to 2018-05-01 there are 6329 days. You can see that for daily de there are only 5824 entries which translates to days. Unless, as I mentioned, I’m doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Convert `date` column into a pandas `datetime` column. Then, group on the `year` and `day` part ignoring the `hour` part to get the `mean`:

```
In [663]: times = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
In [662]: df.groupby([times.dt.year, times.dt.day]).mean()                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[662]: 
            O_3       NO_2       SO_2       PM10       PM25    CO
Date                                                             
1     14.963333  65.831666  17.638333  37.748333  11.087606  0.39
30    52.250000  58.250000   4.000000   4.750000   4.000000  0.30
```

Comment: I'm getting way less entries (days) when implementing it with your code lines, I++m actually getting only 558 entries, I wonder why?. Does .dt count days for every 24 hours and discard in case on not been able to count 24 hours?

Comment: @krm76 `dt.days` does not care about hours at all. It will simply pick all the days mentioned in the date column.

Comment: Your proposed solution was not making any difference at all from the one I was using at the very beginning. Nevertheless I voted up your answer. But I can't consider it as the only answer .